# Faulty function that finds a node in a binary tree

Tags: c, memory-management, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

There is something wrong with this function. It's supposed to find a node with the same value `phone`. I believe it's got problems when it tries to find a node that that doesn't exist.

Here it is:

```
bst_node* find_node(bstree* bst, unsigned long phone) { 
    bst_node* x = bst->root;

    if(x == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if(x->phone == phone)
        return bst->root;

    while (x->phone != phone && (x->left != NULL && x->right != NULL) ) {
        if(phone <= x->phone) {
            x = x->left;
        } else {
            x = x->right;
        }
    }
    if (x->phone == phone) {
        return x;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically your problem was in your while loop. Remember that you can't guarantee that every node will have two children, some nodes may only have one child and you were not exploring those nodes that only had one child. What I do below is separate out the check for the left and right node existence into the conditionals within the while loop. This lets us explore the whole tree :) I also added in an else statement within the while loop because if the node has no children then we have finished exploring and there is no way the node can be in the tree.

```
bst_node* find_node(bstree* bst, unsigned long phone) {

    bst_node* x = bst->root;
    if(x == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if(x->phone == phone)
        return bst->root;
    while (x->phone != phone){
        if(phone <= x->phone && x->left != NULL){
             x = x->left;
        }
        else if (phone > x->phone && x->right != NULL){
             x = x->right;
        }
        else {return NULL;}
    return x;

}
```

Comment: Please add some details explaining what change you made, as well as what issue it fixes.